# How can I get a python script to "remember" user input?

Tags: python

I have a script that asks the user for the path to their desired directory

```
default_path =  '/path/to/desired/directory/'

user_path = raw_input("Enter new directory [{0}]: ".format(default_path)) or default_path

print user_path
```

The script has a "default" directory if no input is given. I want the script to "remember" the directory entered by the user. That is, the next time the script is run I want the default path to be the path input by the last user. Is this possible?

Maybe more generally, is there a good reference for writing command-line tools in python?

Comment: re: your general question.  I wish there was.  I like python as a language, but most CLI tools written in python are horrible.  Most that I've used (including but not limited to the various openstack CLI tools like glance or nova-manage) have awful option processing and, worse, make no effort to produce output that can easily be re-used in other programs (like awk or sed) - it's like many/most python devs have no idea that unix tools are supposed to work WITH other tools and write them as if they're writing a windows CLI tool.  This is not a problem with the language, it's a cultural problem.

Comment: @cas, yes indeed. Would you know of a "shell-think by example for Python developers" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are maintaining the program, then make it store the history. In Python, use the [`readline`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/readline.html) library and make it store a [history file](https://docs.python.org/2/library/readline.html#history-file).

If you don't want to modify the program, you can use a wrapper such as [`rlwrap`](http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/uck/rlwrap/).

```
rlwrap -H ~/.myprogram.history myprogram
```

Answer (score 3):

For this sort of thing, you want to use a configuration file of some sort.  Usually a dotfile in the user's home directory will suffice for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 3):

You should store your information in a file, for which the location adheres to the [XDG Base Directory Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html).

As your material is data and not config you should try if the environment variable `XDG_DATA_HOME` exists and create a file or a utility specific subdirectory under that, where you store the file. If that environment variable does not exists, default to `~/.local/share`:

```
base_dir = os.environ.get('XDG_DATA_HOME', 
                  os.path.join(os.environ['HOME'], '.local', 'share'))
util_data_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, util_name)
```

Comment: Rather than hard-code xdg behavior, use a library that supports all the main OSes, such as [appdirs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/appdirs).